# PHPStorm how to turn project into uploadable plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, deployment

Thank you for reading my question in advance!

This is the first time I work with PHP and wordpress and i am currently working on a previously created project. my question is: when i complete an iteration of this code, how do i prepare it so i can upload it to the wordpress plugin page?

Answer (score 0):

Look in deployment :

```
Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Deployment
```

And setup uploading directly to wp plugin folder.
Then right-click on the folder and upload it to the server.

Comment: maybe an important note: i will deliver the code to a third party and just want to deliver a zip package which contains the plugin. i am not able to connect to the wordpress plugins page.